# Android dual boot on Bq Ubuntu Touch

Tags: android, mobile-phones, ubuntu-touch

Is it possible to install Android onto an Ubuntu Touch phone (Bq Aquaris)? Can you tell me, or send me a description how can I boot from and Android image file. I have seen some similar for Android phones, just I haven't found any for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Kernel for this phone and you can find it in below:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/rom-bq-aquaris-4-5-mt6577-t3028383

and here is:

**[How to Install / Requirements](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=58787127&postcount=2)**

Flashing :

- Put the rom on the EXTERNAL SD Card
- FULL Wipes are mandatory (Cache/dalvik/Data)
- Install the Rom

Also, i'm not sure here is good for this question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: would this be dual boot?